# How can I parent objects from different scenes?

Tags: objects, camera

I have two scenes. Particles in one (blender render), text in the other (Cycles render). I need the camera in the particles scene to move **with** the camera in the other scene - it is for an intro animation. Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: Link the camera between the scenes, see https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/linked_libraries.html.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a problem very much like this when I went to create fireworks. At the time, I assumed the same thing as you, "One must use BR for halo particles." I did not run into the camera problem because I used the *Track To* Object constraint for the cameras so that they would follow the firework's progress. I set the alpha to none and used the alpha over node in the compositor to combine the two scenes.

**The assumption that one must use BR for halo particles, however, is not true.**

Using the point density node as shown in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESZsWNCfpPU) will allow you to use Cycles to render halo particles.

---

**Alternately, to answer the question you asked...**

### Scenes

I used the default Blender startup file for my example, as it has a camera, light source, and object. The first thing I did is duplicate the scene by pressing *New Scene* -> *Full Copy*.

### Animation

Go back to the original scene and insert a key frame at frame one, move the camera, and then insert one at a later frame. The camera should now move when you play the animation. Next, go to the *Animation* Screen Layout. Make sure the scene selected is not the one with the moving camera. Select the non-moving camera. Go to the *Dope Sheet* panel and change the type from *Dope Sheet* to *Action Editor* (the same way you would change from Object to Edit mode in the *3D View*). Where it says *+ New* along the bottom options, click on the dropdown menu to the left side, the same way you would select an old material rather than creating a new material. Somewhere in there should be something resembling **CameraAction**, or **Camera.001Action** (the name of the moving camera followed by **Action**). Click on this. The movement of the two cameras should now be linked.